# Part of the UITextView does not work after resizing

Tags: swift, uitextview

I dynamically change the height of the field. After increasing the height of the field, the enlarged part of the field does not respond to user clicks and scrolling.

```swift
    textView.constraints.forEach{ (constraint) in
        if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
            constraint.constant = constraint.constant - CGFloat(delta) * 16.5
    }
```

How can I increase the gesture recognition area after increasing the height?

Comment: The problem was that my target view was nested in another view (messageInputView) which size did not change. See Sumit Garg solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a height outlet constraints of messageTextView

> ```
> @IBOutlet weak var messageInputViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
> ```

and now change height of outerView according to commentTextView

> self.messageInputViewHeightConstraint = constraint.constant +
>   CGFloat(delta) * 16 + (constant value for spacing purpose)

and run you code it will work

Complete code here :

```
    textView.constraints.forEach{ (constraint) in
        if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
            constraint.constant = constraint.constant - CGFloat(delta) * 16.5
            self.messageInputViewHeightConstraint.constant = constraint.constant + CGFloat(delta) * 16 + (44 - 31)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }}
```

Comment: still not working. I have such a hierarchy of views: https://ibb.co/QFk41Dh

Comment: can you share the screenshot of textView constraint. it may be possible that textview size is increase but supreView height is same.

Comment: Link: https://ibb.co/xqJJbbj
Also link on full func: https://ibb.co/Xk6GPVk
And on init: https://ibb.co/YfnfX5m

Comment: I increase the height of the field on each new line

Comment: you are changing the height of TextView only, should change the outer view(Comment Text View) height as well.

Comment: set messageInputView.clipsToBounds = true, you can understand what should i try to say.

Comment: hmm, with messageInputView.clipsToBounds = true view(Comment Text View) height does not change. Should I change height in a different way?

Comment: you just increase or decrease the height of messageInputView as well. create an outlet of height constraints of messageInputView and put after constraint.constant = constraint.constant - CGFloat(delta) * 16.5. this will work for you

Comment: Ohhhh, I understood, thank you very much, I completely forgot about this view!